# how to read text file which is mixed with emoji in to Pandas Data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, deep-learning

I went to read emoji & text into pandas data frame but it makes question mark like  ???

```
import pandas as pd 
data = 'textwithemoji.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(data, header=None, names=['text','class'],encoding='latin')
```

df

Comment: emojis are from utf-8 encoding

Comment: What does your csv file look like . . . `pd.DataFrame(['\U0001f602'])`

Answer (score 0):

Pandas deals OK with emoji and text in the same column...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

df[['Emojis', 'Meaning']] = df["Emojis"].str.split(' ', 1, expand=True)

print(df)

    Emojis  Meaning
0         Grinning Face.
1         Grinning Face with Big Eyes.
2         Grinning Face with Smiling Eyes.
3         Beaming Face with Smiling Eyes.
4         Grinning Squinting Face.
5         Grinning Face with Sweat.
6         Rolling on the Floor Laughing.
7         Slightly Smiling Face.
```

Example:

[image]

You could add `encoding='utf-8'` if you are having problems.